# is it ok to always git pull --rebase master branch

Tags: git

We are a team working with git, we have a central repository (single origin) we use to `push` and `pull` from (and capistrano use it to deploy the branch master)

we make commits and deploy regularly (10~20 deploys a day), that means we have a lot of merge commit and `git blame` become a nightmare

I've read that to have a simpler history we can use `git pull --rebase` to avoid this. Is it a good idea to do always do this on the master branch?

if it is I'd like to suggest to set it in config with :

```
git config branch.master.rebase true
```

Is there any issue with this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No problem at all.
In fact that is preferred.

99% of the time it's better to rebase the changes in.
If not, the developer can always abort the rebase and merge their changes manually.

The alternative (merging on pull) causes tons of little side commits and merges which don't contribute any meaning.

In general, I don't often see the point of merging local changes.
It implies that there was something special about the exact revision that the developer started on and somehow rebasing to a different revision would cause a loss of information (maybe "I started this before Bob's feature and I want to communicate that in case it doesn't play well with Bob and I get blamed" or something...).
This is rarely actually the case and a clean straight line commit history is a lot easier to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Making pull rebase by default is OK (not necessarily a "good idea", not necessarily a "bad idea" either).  You just need to keep in mind that it will in fact rebase your work.  If you've made a series of commits that all depend on what was in the repo *before* Bob changed it<sup>1</sup>, your rebase (on top of Bob's changes) may force you to fix up all those commits, when it might have been easier to fix up only the final merge commit.

I prefer to do this manually: run `git fetch`, and then `git rebase` or `git merge` depending on the situation, which I can discover once I have done the fetch.

There's an advantage to `git pull --rebase` (and/or setting `branch.master.rebase true`) though, in that a "pull with rebase" is extra-smart and can handle some cases where the remote has done rebases too.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Bob" here represents anyone who made some change (and beat you to the `push` step) that causes your own changes to "have indigestion", as it were.

Answer (score 2):

It's always fine pull.rebase in my expierence. If you don't want to have merge conflicts you can work in a local branch, and if you want to work with latest code you'll always prefer to have any uncommited changes before your current work is pushed.

Merging in a branch as a result of `git pull` is almost always meaningless, if merge would be meaningful branches should have been different (and merge explicit).

See also http://stevenharman.net/git-pull-with-automatic-rebase.

Answer (score -4):

You should never rebase any revision that exists in other repository and might have another work based on it, because that work would than need to be rebased too.

If you push a branch and then rebase it, you will have to use `-f` option to next push. So if you never use that option, you never get in the problematic situation and can rebase freely. But if you push with `-f`, perhaps to a feature branch, then be careful not to rebase when other people may be working on that branch too or coordinate the rebase with them.

So for your own development work, by all means, rebase (and rebase -i and combine and split changes etc. to make them more logical). But if more than one person works on a feature, rebasing would need coordination which might no longer be worth it and rebasing published development branch is basically off limits.

Comment: as we only pull/push from the central repository, nobody can pull from _my_ master branch so I can't rebase work that exists in other repositories by `git pull --rebase master`. can I? of course feature branches are only rebase when not published. I'm just talking about master here

Comment: @Mathieu: Nobody can pull your master, but if you push your master into a development branch in the central repository, than somebody else can use it and you shouldn't rebase it then.

Comment: This answer is wrong unless you're pushing master out with -f and/or pushing it to different upstream repositories which are never resynced with the master repo. If you don't do that, the history being rewritten is by definition limited to unshared local commits.

Comment: @ChrisAdams: How does that make this answer _wrong_, though? If you don't push with `-f` (it does not have to be _master_ specifically; you can push a feature branch with `-f` while somebody else may need to merge it) you won't run into the problematic case. That does not make the case unproblematic.

Comment: The first sentence: “You should never rebase any revision that exists in other repository and might have another work based on it, because that work would than need to be rebased too”. If you are always rebasing only the commits which have not yet been shared (i.e. what `git pull --rebase master` actually does) then that sentence is talking about a situation which doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChrisAdams: And the question asked whether it's _always_ OK. Therefore I explained when it is not. Yes, it is not the standard situation. But it is not like it may not happen - we have many branches on which multiple people work.